# Rotate arrow on hover over to land at certain degree and load image

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for someone to help guide me in the right direction for a function I'm trying to create.

I need to create an arrow that when at a certain point of degree, a tree grows, I have created 7 different heights and 7 different images for the tree's for a clean look.

Basically you know how you can have an image and rotate it using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var img = $('.image');
if(img.length > 0){
var offset = img.offset();
function mouse(evt){
    var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width()/2);
    var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height()/2);
    var mouse_x = evt.pageX; var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
    var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
    var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90; 
    img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
}
$(document).mousemove(mouse);
}
</script>
```

But how do I get my arrow to stop at 20 degree's, 25 degree's, 30 degree's etc etc.. while at the same time loading the new image i have assigned to that certain degree (whatever the tip of the arrow is pointed at) all doing this by hover over.

And not only do stop and load the new image, but also once the user clicks submit it adds data to my tree table within my db. So basically, its an arrow, the tip of the arrow gets set at a certain degree, loads the new image, takes the height of the image (i need some way of assigning the height var to each individual image im guessing?) then query that into my tree table under the tree height field.

Any help, links to get me started would be greatly appreciated.

Also, is there a way to do this with Canvas or SVG? Instead of using a arrow image as my arrow? For a more clean look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might render an arrow following the mouse using `canvas`.
http://jsbin.com/inufoy/edit

Locking the rotation of the arrow to certain points is as simple as filtering the parameter on the draw function. eg:

```
var segs = 7;
var coefficient = Math.PI / segs;
r -= ((r + coefficient) % (coefficient * 2)) - coefficient;
```

From there all you have to do is assign each image a rotation, and check when the arrow is pointing towards the tree, then load the tree's image.

**Edit:**
Here's another version of that script with a static arrow base such as your description:
http://jsbin.com/inufoy/5/edit

Comment: How to i get the bottom of the arrow to stay put while only the tip moves using images. As far as details go, i dont think i could go into details any further, Ive explained it to the T... Would you like me to draw out an example?

Comment: Just added a modified example for an arrow where the tip moves but the base doesn't. As for the images, you could easily do that with a mousemove event and have that perhaps modify the appearence of the arrow for visual feedback other than the tree growing. It's entirely dependent on your implementation.

Comment: Now all i need is the effect where the arrow stops at a certain degree if i can get them to stop i can finish the coding from there. I see your var segs example above... is that the type of method i would use for this effect?

Comment: Yes, you'd put that at the top of the drawArrow function in this case.

Comment: Can you explain to me what this line does?

Sorry new to JS, i can handle JS until i start seeing things like r.. and % and whats -=   ?

Comment: Ohhhhhhh im starting to understand it now i think.. the r is for the rotate am i correct?

Comment: Ahhh yes. Alright, allow me to explain:

The r in this case is for radians or rotation, either way it's still the same.

The % is the modulo operator, it gives you the remainder of a division, rather than the result. So `57 / 10 = 5.7` where `57 % 10 = 7`